# Android passing string to recyclerview

Tags: android, json, adapter, android-recyclerview

I am trying to pass the string data which I get from web service and trying to show them in recyclerview. Here is the code which initializes the recyclerview's data.

```
private static final String URL_CROSSSERVICE = "http://xxx";
private static final String TOKEN = "xxx";
private static final String USER_NAME = "xx";
List<NewsData> newsDatas = new ArrayList<>();
Toolbar toolbar;
private RecyclerView rv;
public NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment;
String newsImageUrl, newsTitle,newsDesc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Haberler");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);

    rv= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

    NewsAdapter adapter= new NewsAdapter(this, newsDatas);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    initializeData();
}
 .
 .
 .
private void initializeData() {

    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    VolleySingleton volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
    requestQueue = volleySingleton.getRequestQueue();

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_CROSSSERVICE,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    JSONObject sitePage = response;
                    try {
                        JSONArray newsPageContents= sitePage.getJSONArray("Contents");

                        for (int i = 0; i < newsPageContents.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject newsContent = (JSONObject) newsPageContents.get(i);
                            newsTitle = newsContent.getString("Name");
                            newsDesc = newsContent.getString("Description");
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Token", TOKEN);
            headers.put("Username", USER_NAME);
            return headers;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(request);

    newsDatas.add(new NewsData(newsTitle, newsDesc, R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    newsDatas.add(new NewsData("Lavery Maiss", "25 years old", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    newsDatas.add(new NewsData("Lillie Watts", "35 years old", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

}
```

Last two lines are intentionally left hard coded, in order to see if adapter is working or not. Here is the adapter class.

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder> {
private Context context;
List<NewsData> datas;
public NewsAdapter(Context context,List<NewsData> datas){
    this.datas=datas;
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view,parent,false);
    NewsViewHolder newsViewHolder= new NewsViewHolder(v);
    return newsViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NewsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.newsName.setText(datas.get(position).Name);
    holder.newsDesc.setText(datas.get(position).Description);
    holder.newsImage.setImageResource(datas.get(position).photoURL);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return datas.size();
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

public class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cv;
    TextView newsName;
    TextView newsDesc;
    ImageView newsImage;

    public NewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_news);
        newsName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.newsTitle);
        newsDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.newsDesc);
        newsImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.newsImage);
    }
}
```

}

The problem is following. As you can see at the first code block, when I try to add string to **NewsDatas** array,it is not shown on recylerview, but hardcoded lines works fine. **newsTitle** and **newsDesc** are both string. Do you know why it happens? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after you added data to NewsData.

Comment: I removed the hard coded lines and used it right after this: newsDatas.add(new NewsData(newsTitle, newsDesc, R.mipmap.ic_launcher)); but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I added my datas in the for loop and after the addition I called **rv.getAdapter().NotifyDatasetChanged();** like this:

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    JSONObject sitePage = response;
                    try {
                        JSONArray newsPageContents = sitePage.getJSONArray("Contents");

                        for (int i = 0; i < newsPageContents.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject newsContent = (JSONObject) newsPageContents.get(i);
                            newsTitle = newsContent.getString("Name");
                            newsDesc = newsContent.getString("Description");
                            Utils.message(newsTitle);
                            Utils.message(newsDesc);
                            newsDatas.add(new NewsData(newsTitle, newsDesc, R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
                            rv.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thanks @Tan Tran!